# how to populate audit columns in the database while loading data from Json to oracle table?

Tags: apache-nifi, apache-nifi-toolkit, nifi-processor

Imagine I have employees json file which needs to be populated into employees table in oracle using Apache Nifi.

my source file does not have the time of insert and update, I want to populate created time with processing time, created user name with process name. Is it possible to implement in Nifi?

input:
[{"id":1,"name":"John"},
{"id"2,"name:"Katie"}]

Output:

| id | Name | createdDate | UpdatedDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 01-jan-2020 | 01-jan-2020 |
| 2 | Katie | 01-jan-2020 | 05-jan-2020 |

how do I achieve this in Nifi?

Tried with putSql and PutDataBaseRecord processes, none of them works for update, while inserting, actual columns are insert, but not the audit columns.